# Форматирование чисел с помощью openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Пишу программу для парсинга всех балансов на одном сайте и затем запись их в файл xlsx. Но после записи имею ошибку, число сохранено как текст. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, как форматировать текст.
Код, который я пробую:

```
def write_to_table(ids, balances):
    salary = load_workbook('salary.xlsx')
    ws = salary.active
    for row in range(0, len(ids)):
        cell_name = 'A{}'.format(row + 1)
        ws[cell_name] = ids[row]
        cell_name = 'B{}'.format(row + 1)
        ws[cell_name] = balances[row]
        ws[cell_name].number_format = '0.00'
        
    salary.save('salary.xlsx')
```

Приходят числа вроде 5.65 или -50.00 и нужно, чтобы Excel понял, что это числа. Так понимаю, проблема в этой строке:

```
ws[cell_name].number_format = '0.00'
```

Прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: а что у вас находится в `balances` - строки или числа? Вы не пробовали использовать модуль Pandas? Он идеально подходит для вашей задачи...

Comment: Спасибо за совет, да, там лежат строки.

Comment: Очевидно форматирование чисел работает для чисел, а не для строк ;)

Answer (score 0):

Просто конвертируй их с помощью `float()`:

```
ws[cell_name].number_format = float('0.00')
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).